# oracle missing right parenthesis ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE

Tags: oracle

using oracle database

**error: missing right parenthesis**

line: 'on overflow'

```
select DISTINCT 
        m.id, 
        LISTAGG(ps.col1, ' \n ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...' WITHOUT COUNT) WITHIN group (order by ps.col1) as randomNames,
        from monday m
```

Comment: Are you trying to use [Oracle 12cR2 syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html) on a [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm) (or earlier) database?

Answer (score 6):

The [overflow clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html#GUID-B6E50D8E-F467-425B-9436-F7F8BF38D466) was added in Oracle 12c release 2.

[image]

You get that error if you try to use it in an earlier version, even 12c release 1.

Compare the documentation for [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm) and [12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LISTAGG.html).

Comment: how can i do this in release 1?